# How to filter in PUB/SUB with protobuf binaries?

Tags: protocol-buffers, zeromq, publish-subscribe

Suppose I want to serialize and transmit protobuf binaries with ZMQ using a protocol defined in `cake.proto`:

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Cake {
    int32 radius = 1;
}
```

I can find plenty of examples for the PUB/SUB pattern where a subscriber filters a topic with a string:
`socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "abc")`

But how does subscribing to topics work when it comes to protobuf binaries? Do I use the bytes themselves or does ZMQ provide an wrapper for a message with a header I can use for cases like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no wrapper for this, the subject is just the first frame of the zeromq message.

If you are confident your protobuf messages will always start with the specific sequence of bytes (that make your subject) then yes you can just subscribe to that byte prefix pattern.

The other option is to copy the subject pattern into an initial frame then add the protobuf frame(s) via `ZMQ_SNDMORE`. If you can pack many protobuf frames into that same zmq message then the efficiency is good. If each protobuf message has its own "subject" then you will have the overhead of an extra subject frame per protobuf.

Comment: Yep that's right, I just didn't realise (and in my opinion it's not very well documented anywhere) that when the payload is raw binary, in order to use PUB/SUB you kind of have to use multipart (or things get very ugly).

Comment: The first approach is somewhat described [here](https://www.dotkam.com/2011/09/09/zeromq-and-google-protocol-buffers/), but my advice is to not use it as (AFAIK) order in which fields are serialized is not defined. The latter approach works perfectly.

Comment: Hi, if we send the initial frame with the pattern and then just append multiple frames, wouldn't subscribers that start later miss these frames?